# Making android ROM "e:signature verification failed"

Tags: android, cygwin, rom

I have a ROM (zip file) which I put it inside SDCard and then flash phone in boot.

I extracted the zip file, removed an app (or even tested without any change to stock ROM) then zipped the package (by winrarzip archive). Put it inside phone and getting error:

- e:signature verification failed

I noticed stock ROM zip archive had a comment called "signed by APKsign". So, I installed cygwin and prepared kitchen. Put stock zip ROM in "Original update", set up working folder from ROM, then built ROM from working folder, signed the package during making ROM, BUT again:

- e:signature verification failed

Then I tried Rooting the package (2.Add root permission) before making ROM.

- The same problem

Then I tried unzipping stock ROM, Then zip it again with winrarzip archive. Put this zip file in Original update folder, Then using (0. Advance option) and (22. sign apk or zip files), then sign this zip file.

- The same problem

What is the problem? Why can't phone detect the signature in spite of being signed by kitchen?
My ROM is "huaqin75_cu_ics-ota" it is the ROM for MT6575 phone.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions here, one is to disable signature checking in your recovery (CWM/TWRP) this would be a temporary quick solution however the permanent solution

we ca try resigning using java, **i created a simple script with a gui years ago** to do this for me when i was hacking into early android http://www.modaco.com/topic/313829-pc-tool-zip-signer-v11/ for windows only

when i had my huawei pulse mini i used a dodgy recovery which gave me a similar sort of error for a portion of signed zips